# What is the right way to use `useFactory` and `deps:[ ]` in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use a simple provider with `useFactory` which will also use `deps` (*learning purpose*) .

So I've created this [**plnkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wIL40Htfmacqj1K9xLGW?p=preview) :

```
//app.module.ts
...
const randomFactory = (car,engine) => { return new Calc(car,engine);  };
 ...
 providers: [Car,Engine, 
             { provide: 'Random', 
               useFactory: randomFactory ,  
               deps: [Car, Engine],
             },
            ]
```

Where `Calc` is :

```
export class Calc
{
  car:Car;
  engine:Engine;

  constructor ( Engine engine, Car car)
   {
    this.car=car;
    this.engine=engine;
   }
  doSomething(){alert(this.car.getInfo() + this.engine.getInfo()}
}
```

Now  I want to use it as an injected object  so I did this :

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('Random') r) {
    r.doSomething(); //should alert "car data + engine data" , but I get an error.
   }
}
```

But I get an error : *car is not defined*

**Question:**

*I don't see any point of using `deps:[]` If I already declare that modules in the main app module ( and so it is known in the global app) and in the `Calc` class where I import those classes.*

So how can I fix my code to use  `deps:[]` the right way ?

[**plnkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wIL40Htfmacqj1K9xLGW?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The providers configuration is correct. You've got a syntax error in the `Calc` constructor. The correct declaration of the arguments is as follows:

```
constructor (engine: Engine, car: Car){
```

Here is the updated plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/HsECR0HEcIaPNbK6A7ZZ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks ( too much C#). So why do I need `deps` if `Car` and `Engine` is already known in the global module scope?

Comment: @Royi It determines what should providers are needed and the order of arguments passed to the factory function

Comment: As @peeskillet said, someone should tell the Angular what parameters should be passed to the factory function.